Epistemic Concern Regarding Black Holes
A lot of work has been done in recent years regarding black holes, especially in the area of thermodynamics. However this raises in me a philosophical concern: since not even light can escape a black hole (that is, the entire collapsed star is beneath its event horizon), we cannot gain any empirical data about what lies beneath its event horizon. Let me give an example of just how weird the math gets.
For a rotating black hole, the Kerr metric predicts that encircled by the ring singularity is a "portal" to a "negative space" or "antiverse", where gravity is repulsive instead of attractive. Now, many scientists think these features probably don't obtain, since there's a inner (Cauchy) horizon with infinite blueshift that one must cross first.
Wild stuff. While many scientists are skeptical that the Kerr metric is accurate this close to the ring singularity, I keep thinking of "it must be falsifiable!" Given the physical impossibility of gaining empirical data of what lies below the event horizon of a black hole (which includes any potential inner Cauchy horizons), should we relegate all speculation of what lies beneath the outer event horizon as being beyond empirical science?

I wouldn't call "the direct implications of our models, which have been demonstrated to work in a wide variety of novel situations" pseudoscience. Even if it's not strictly verifiable, it's different entirely from speculations that are entirely disconnected from effective models.

@TKoL I wouldn't either, but this falsifiable criterion bothers me.

If the model as a whole is falsifiable, but it also makes non-falsifiable claims as a direct consequence of other aspects of the model being true, is it that bothersome? I actually think not.

Just as an example, my model of the world says solid macroscopic objects continue to exist when I'm not looking. I once threw a ball up in the air as a child, and stopped looking and walked away, and the ball reminded me of its continued existence with great momentum on the top of my head. If I extrapolate further, I can conclude that even when the Voyager spacecraft will no longer be practically detectable by human technology, the Voyager spacecraft will still exist. Is it unreasonable to think Voyager still exists when it's unfalsifiable?

@TKoL I think those are excellent examples. Perhaps I don't need to be so worried about this then.

We have to allow our models to have consequences, and it's okay even to believe in those consequences when we can't see them. Now obviously I can't tell you how confident you should be that these black suns are truly the necessary consequence of modern physics understanding, but if they are, I have no intellectual issue with someone talking about them as if they're real, just as I have no intellectual issue with talking about Voyager as if it still exists.

A hot topic in physics is the ability of information to cross the event horizon. For any theory of the interior of a black hole to be falsifiable requires information passing back and forth across the event horizon OR that the information can be inferred from the externally viewed behavior.

Why are not you asking this in Physics.SE?

@Anixx They tend to close my questions over there, also this is more a question about the philosophy of science, and not science itself.

@VictorBergman I wonder why my questions are always closed on Philosophy.SE? On Physics, it seems, there is no such problem.

Is "black sun" another name for "black hole"? I've never heard it before.

@Barmar Oh yes, I suppose everyone calls them "black holes" now.

@Barmar it is a 18th century term for black holes.

@TKoL I think your comments together do a good job of answering this question, and it would be quite reasonable to repost them as an answer.

"negative space" or "antiverse" <- Whoever wrote that was really high.

I don't follow but came across this and wonder if it's of interest or dimly related. https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2024/11/30/black-hole-puzzle/

As far as we know, it is totally possible to make empirical observations past the event horizon of a black hole. You just can't communicate those observations back to your colleagues on Earth. As long as you only want to test the theory for your own personal edification, then it is indeed falsifiable. That is an epistemic problem in the same sense that we can't know what it feels like to die; in fact, we can know, but finding out prevents us from telling anyone about it.

@CosmicGenis There's a bottle of sixty year old brandy I like to indulge in when doing speculative physics . . .


Given the physical impossibility of gaining empirical data of what
lies below the event horizon of a black hole

This given can't be given. "Right now on the other side of an event horizon" and "previously on the other side of an event horizon" are phrases that don't denote anything, like right now tomorrow and yesterday tomorrow. (Exactly like that: here and now is the event horizon with the past on one side and the future on the other.)
It's not impossible to find the answer, it's impossible to ask the question. This is an epistemic problem - but not the one you've described.
This doesn't mean we can't ask other questions about the same region which can be empirically assessed. Exactly as we can ask and answer meaningful questions about the things in the future of here-and-now (including futures much too far away to wait for) by studying the past-somewhere-else, we can ask and answer meaningful questions about black holes by studying the past-outside.
They just can't be questions about the current state of the other side of the event horizon any more than questions in flat spacetime about states in the future of here and now can be questions about the current state of future states.

(Generally when a physicist talks about how the other side of an event horizon "is" they mean or ought to mean something like "how it would be if you went there".)

This is an excellent point, I was guilty of treating the region beyond the event horizon as a place in space, and not spacetime. Specifically, the radial coordinate "becomes" the temporal coordinate beyond the event horizon. We think it's quite valid for physics to discuss the future even though we lack time machines. Regions beyond an event horizon are no different!

It is an area of current research in physics, but in general we know that all physical processes are reversible in time, if some process can happen, a reverse process can happen as well. This means that if information cannot be retrieved from under the event horizon, it could not get there in the first place, and if information can fall to under the event horizon, then it can be retrieved from there one way or another.

Ah, so the very premise of my question is mistaken: either we can know what happens to black suns as they collapse beneath an event horizon, or there's no information there to begin with. Very helpful!

@VictorBergman exactly. And the current proposed theories are divided on this. https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-the-inside-of-a-black-hole-is-secretly-on-the-outside/

Great Source! I'll spend some time reading up on this.

Black holes introduce a number of paradoxes, which physicists find disturbing. I think the hope is that unification of general relativity and quantum mechanics will resolve them. @VictorBergman

@Barmar Yes, that also looms in the background of my question. Perhaps it was more appropriate for it to be on Physics.SE afterall. I've gotten more than I wanted here, will take some time to digest. Thanks everyone!

Classical fluid dynamics describes physical systems from whose state at a given moment, none of the earlier states can be deduced. Consider the motion of a point particle under hydrodynamic drag in a pseudoplastic fluid, i.e., a fluid in which the drag scales slower than linearly with the velocity of the object. Unlike the case of a Newtonian fluid, in a pseudoplastic fluid the object reaches zero velocity in finite time. So if you only know that the object is currently at velocity zero, you cannot deduce whether it was in motion sometime in the past, or when.

My point is that there are indeed plausible physical systems in which you do not have the kind of time-reversibility you describe, and indeed information is lost. Pseudoplastic fluids are commonplace, e.g. ketchup or non-drip paint. Mathematically, here is what is happening: if you represent the pseudoplastic case of hydrodynamic drag as a force field, it is continuous but not Lipschitz-continuous in an open neighborhood of v=0. So the Picard-Lindelof theorem does not give you uniqueness of solutions to the initial value problem. Indeed you get many solutions to the ODE with initial value v=0.

@user509184 fluid dynamics does not describe an isolated system. If a system is well isolated, it undergoes unitary evolution, which is totally reversible.

@ user509184 You don't even have to consider pseudoplastic fluids to counter the argument that all systems are reversible. Any fluid flow is irreversible if friction effects are included.

@VictorBergman the argument used in this answer is incorrect. While it is true that Einstein's equation is time reversible, the time reverse of a black hole is a white hole. In a white hole information can never enter the white hole just as with a black hole information can never leave the black hole. If we consider just GR, so leaving aside the unresolved issue of Hawking radiation, then once information has crossed the event horizon it is gone for good.

@JohnRennie information either cannot enter and leave or it can enter and leave. White hole is just a low-probability state of a black hole. All physical equations, those of GR or QM are time-symmetric.

@JohnRennie I take your expertise seriously, and so since this answer seems contentious I've removed the "accepted answer" status it once had. Thanks! Next time I'll ask such questions on Physics.SE!

@VictorBergman it's a good question, and my response as a physicist would be to say we know from experiment that GR works outside the horizon so we assume it works inside the horizon. However I suspect a philosopher would regard this as naïve and I don't know enough about philosophy to say anything more profound. I'm surprised your question got closed. Maybe the philosophers hereabouts thought you were asking about physics.

@JohnRennie "just GR" is a wrong approach to the black holes because pure GR is not applicable to the times, comparable to the BH evaporation, if by "just GR" you mean the Swartzschield solution, it describes a stationary, non-evaporating black hole. My answer is absolutely correct and your claim that information can be lost in a black hole is completely unphysical and contradicts quantum mechanics.

@VictorBergman my answer is absolutely correct. There is no known law of nature that is not time-reversible. There is nothing controversial about it.
